should you store block.timestamp in a variable in memory for gas optimizations for loops?
I want to execute a function like the following:
    function calculateUserVotingPower(address _user) public view returns (uint256 userVotingPower) {
    IVoteEscrow.NFTInfo[] memory nfts = voteEscrow.getUserAllNFTs(_user);
    uint256 length = nfts.length;
    if (length > MAX_NFTS_CONSIDERED) revert TooManyNFTs();

    for (uint256 i = 0; i < length; ) {
        if (nfts[i].locked_end > block.timestamp) {
            userVotingPower += nfts[i].balanceOf;
        }
        unchecked {
            ++i;
        }
    }
}

So, in such functions, does it save gas to cache block.timestamp variable and use it for comparisons?
for eg.
    function calculateUserVotingPower(address _user) public view returns (uint256 userVotingPower) {
IVoteEscrow.NFTInfo[] memory nfts = voteEscrow.getUserAllNFTs(_user);
uint256 length = nfts.length;
if (length > MAX_NFTS_CONSIDERED) revert TooManyNFTs();

uint256 timestamp = block.timestamp;
for (uint256 i = 0; i < length; ) {
    if (nfts[i].locked_end > timestamp) {
        userVotingPower += nfts[i].balanceOf;
    }
    unchecked {
        ++i;
    }
}

}
Other than loops, if block.timestamp, msg.sender or address(this) if used multiple times, should they be cached in memory and then used to save gas?

I ran some tests, and the difference is around 1 gas each loop. So just pick what looks best for you.

In case of msg.sender, reading from memory consumes 3 gas (mload opcode) and getting the address of the sender consumes 2 gas (caller opcode). Essentially, saving the variable in memory and reading it afterwards is more expensive than using msg.sender every time.

In his case he's not using mload but reading from the stack. So it's all about stack manipulation (DUP, POP, etc..)
